# How to support other language in EditText's setError popup msg in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to display `error message` in `popup` in selected `specific language` in edit text.

Ex.:
`editText.setError(R.string.common_title);`

But, It is showing me a `blank popup` of edit text.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `editText.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.common_title))` ?

Comment: @joao86 - Yes I have tried this. In `English` It is showing proper message. But The popup goes blank when I change the `Local language` in app.

Comment: Do you have the translation set in your strings.xml file for R.string.common.title?

Comment: @joao86 - Yes I have `strings.xml` files for supported language.

Comment: @joao86 -I am testing it on real device and Device does not support `Gujarati` language. That is why I have created `CustomEditText` with support `typeface`. And edittext displays the texts in `Gujarati` language but `error message` comes blank.

Comment: Please check if other strings are appearing in language selected.

Comment: @Mudassir - Yes Every strings are appearing well. Only `edittext popup` error message display blank In `Gujarati` language.

Comment: Try changing the error message to another string and see if it appears. Besides that I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: post your custom edit text class

Comment: @joao86 - Ok Thanks

Comment: In that case, make sure string is named `R.string.common_title` in Gujarati strings.xml files.

Comment: @Mudassir - string is named is correct in both resource file with `R.string.common_title`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You have Different string files for different languages as per [official Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization)

EDIT: If your gradle file have this line **resConfig "en"**, remove it.

Comment: I have already differenet string resource files for every language which I want to support

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati If your gradle file have this line resConfig "en", remove it.

Comment: @PrasantHingrajiya  gradle file does not have this line `resConfig "en"`.

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati please go to Language & input setting in your Device setting, and check if gujarati is supported?

Comment: @PrashantHingrajiya - No Gujarati is not supported.

Comment: Then it will not be displayed, your phone must have gujarati language.

Comment: Please run this code in phone which has Gujarati support.

Comment: @PrashantHingrajiya - `Gujarati supported phone display error message properly.` But I want support it in every device, That is why I have created `CustomEditText` which support gujarati fonts.